# Migrating with subdirectory branch

Tags: svn, mercurial

I'm trying to convert an SVN repository to Mercurial.  A few hundred revisions ago, a branch was made from a subdirectory of trunk (rather than the whole of trunk).

```
trunk
  * subdir
  * ...
branches
  * foo (forked from subdir)
  * ... (other branches fork from trunk)
tags
  * ...
```

I attempted to convert the repository using the convert extension, but foo is causing problems.  It shows up in the converted repository, not as a branch from trunk but one from a new branch named "subdir".  The subdir branch parallels trunk and any change made to trunk is duplicated on subdir.

Here's an abridged view of the repository after conversion:

```
  .
  .
  |
  *  202  foo      Created foo branch
. |
. *  201  subdir   Added XYZ
| |
* .  200  default  Added XYZ
| .
. .
. |
. *    4  subdir   Fixed DEF
| |
* |    3  default  Fixed DEF
| |
| *    2  subdir   Added ABC
|  
*      1  default  Added ABC
```

Instead of:

```
  .
  .
. |
. *  101  foo      Created foo branch
|/
*    100  default  Added XYZ
|
.
.
.
|
*      2  default  Fixed DEF
|  
*      1  default  Added ABC
```

How can I fix the repository (either pre- or post-conversion) so that the branching matches the second diagram?

Answer (score 0):

## Post-conversion way

You have two tasks:

- Remove duplicates revisions from subdir branch
- Change parent for 1-st real changeset of foo branch

### You can use different ways to kill changesets prior 202 in "subdir"

- MQ (2 versions)

  - convert changesets to mq-patches, unapply all patches, delete patches
  - convert changesets to mq-patches, unapply all patches, clone repository to new, use new forever
- Histedit extension (bundled with TortoiseHG) - enable, use, delete all bad commits

### Linking foo branch to the right parent

`hg rebase -s 202 -d 200` (according to your first graph, using hashes or bookmarks /add it/ will be nicer and more bulletproof). Isolated changesets of "subdir" will disappear after `hg clone -r tip`

Comment: I tried rebasing which almost worked except it left stuff in subdir at the root level.  So `/subdir/bar.txt` after the rebase is now `/bar.txt` and the old version of `bar.txt` is still in `/subdir`.  The rebased changesets also lost their branch name but I think that could be fixed with `--keepbranches`.